How to switch between 2 power levels for mq7 sensor
I am using mq7 sensor for my project.For this sensor according to the datasheet I need to continuously switch between 5 and 1.5 V input voltage to mq7 sensor. Since I am a beginner, wanted to know how can I implement this, I am using esp32 microcontroller.


For this, you need a buck/boost converter driven with a GPIO pin (low/high) of the ESP32 microcontroller (power supply 3.3V if I remember well). MQ7 is very "hungry", some 150 mA?

You can continually switch but I don't think you can continuously switch i.e. it's a contradiction. Please link the data sheet for the device and explain what page you found this information.

I have referred this datasheet https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/MQ-7.pdf
On 2nd page there is information about this.

Here is a "starting" schematic made with microcap v12.
The resistor of the "heater" should be 33 Ohm.
Note that for 1.5V, the Duty1 = 0.01 -> PWM for Q4 is ... not applicated, Q4 is off.

And results simulated ... The value of R4 may be higher.
Low voltage output = 1.5 V.

High voltage output = 5 V.

